# Glob matching only returning first match

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, parameters

I'm coding up a sort of custom `rm` script that I would like to pass wildcard matches to. I have several files in the working directory that would match the wildcard that I'm passing to the script, but I'm only getting one of them back from a simple test case:

```
sh remove r*
```

Inside the `remove` script, I've whittled it down to just

```
echo $1
```

Here's the directory contents:

```
$ ls
file2  file4          newTestFile  remove_engine  restore
file3  fileName_1234  remove       remove_w       restore_engine
```

And here's what I get back.

```
$ sh remove r*
remove
```

I understand that BASH expands the wildcard out even before the script is executed. But why am I not getting all of the files in the directory that match `f*`?

Comment: `$1` is the first match. `$2` is the second. `"$@"` is all of them

Comment: Note that the root issue has nothing to do with globbing. You could reproduce the same problem with `sh remove foo bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pathname expansion, aka globbing, expands a single shell word into multiple. In your case

```
./remove r*
```

is entirely identical to running

```
./remove remove remove_engine restore remove remove_w restore_engine
```

As you discovered, `$1` will be `remove` because this is the first argument. The rest of the files are separate positional parameters, so `$2` will be `remove_engine` and `$3` will be `restore`.

To process all of the arguments, you use `"$@"`, either in a loop:

```
for file in "$@"
do
  printf 'One of the matches was: %s\n' "$file"
done
```

or just directly in commands that also accept multiple parameters:

```
# Delete all matches
echo rm "$@"
```